# Eclipse build path issue - can't add my project to tomcat server 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-indigo, jakarta-ee

I can't add my project to tomcat server 7, so i went to properties of my project and Dynamic Web module was unchecked. When i try to check that box.

But i got the below error. Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `remove module` configureation from the eclipse setting.

Edit `<workspave>\<project>\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
    <installed facet="jst.web" version="x.x"/> <-- remove that line.
</faceted-project>
```

Try again as your picture at IDE.

Answer (score 1):

just select the version of Dynamic Web Module  from 3.0 to 2.5 . if you have any problem ,reply this

Answer (score 0):

Clean the .classpath of your project.

Then you can check the box of dynamic web module 3.0.

After checked, you can add the project to your server.